# How to move a prefab to the desired position in scrollview in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a prefab consists of two buttons horizontally.I am able to get list with those prefabs but now I need to swap positions of the clone prafabs.For example I have three clones now i have to move third clone to fist or second position.How do i get that?

here is how i am getting list

```
var WordGroup = Instantiate(DeletePrefab);
SelectedWordsPrefabModel prefabModel = WordGroup.GetComponent<SelectedWordsPrefabModel>();                            
prefabModel.SelectedWordBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = word.Word;
WordGroup.transform.SetParent(Content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use some layout component, e.g. *Horizontal Layout Group*, to position your children automatically and just to set the sibling index instead of calculating positions manually.

```
someGameObject.transform.SetSiblingIndex(newIndexNumber);
```

This reorders the children in the hierarchy view, which is used by layout components. Indexes are counted zero-based, so set the index of the third child to 0.

See also: [Auto Layout reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html)

Comment: Thank you @Quasimodo's clone,i will try this .